# Getting NullPointerException from Hashtable while using GObject method

Tags: java, netbeans, hashtable

So I try to create a small Zombie-Shooter game. I use a GTurtle class from ACM package (jtf.acm.org). I have additional thread for a GTurtle, which is a GObject. I have a run method with while loop, that is checking if boolean is true, if it is - this.forward() method gets executed.

I tried running game and pressing button, if it is W or D, boolean in GTurtle object gets changed and Thread executes action. Then I get this exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
         at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:394)
         at acm.util.JTFTools.pause(JTFTools.java)
         at acm.util.Animator.delay(Animator.java)
         at acm.graphics.GTurtle.setLocation(GTurtle.java)
         at acm.graphics.GObject.move(GObject.java)
         at acm.graphics.GTurtle.move(GTurtle.java)
         at acm.graphics.GObject.movePolar(GObject.java)
         at acm.graphics.GTurtle.forward(GTurtle.java)
         at anotherTryJava.Player.run(Player.java:20)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Judging by the source code for `Hashtable.put` you either passed `key` parameter with `null` or `value` parameter with `null` or both `null`.

From [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#put%28K,%20V%29).

> #### Throws:
>
> `NullPointerException` - if the key or value is `null`

Note: I do not know the version of the JDK you are using (link below does not have a line 394 matching with your version), although the reasoning remains valid!

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Hashtable.java.html

```
public synchronized V put(K key, V value) {
    if (key != null && value != null) {
        [...]
        return result;
    }
    throw new NullPointerException();
}

Hashtable a = ...;
a.put(null, "s"); // NullPointerException
a.put("s", null); // NullPointerException
```

Comment: It's interesting to see that your quote is an exact copypaste from my answer's source.

Comment: shameless copy paste of ONLY the javadoc quote part @BalusC, i admit. to my avail, was to avoid copying/trimming it all over again from oracle website. if i could +1 you for the work on that i would!

Comment: I solved the problem by changing logic of the game. I used variables for location X and Y, and created method to do a step. Thanks for the answer. I found some new things on Hashtabels.